# How to avoid "Component is declared but its value is never read." when I use Vue3 setup syntax?

Tags: vuejs3, vscode-extensions, vetur

```xml
<template>
  <ConfigProvider :locale="getAntdLocale">
    <AppProvider>
      <RouterView />
    </AppProvider>
  </ConfigProvider>
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ConfigProvider } from 'ant-design-vue';
  import { AppProvider } from '/@/components/Application';
  import { useTitle } from '/@/hooks/web/useTitle';
  import { useLocale } from '/@/locales/useLocale';

  // support Multi-language
  const { getAntdLocale } = useLocale();

  // Listening to page changes and dynamically changing site titles
  useTitle();
</script>
```

Vetur shows this warning:

```
'ConfigProvider' is declared but its value is never read.Vetur(6133)

'getAntdLocale' is declared but its value is never read.Vetur(6133)
```

It seems the template can't read the script with setup syntax variable. How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Vetur has [no support](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2296) for `script setup` yet - it is planned for [v0.37.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/milestone/12) (current version is 0.34.1)

As of now, [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) is better choice for using `script setup` and TS and is [recommended](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/378#discussioncomment-1158805) even by Evan You (Vue creator). I'm using it and it is really great!

UPDATE:
And with [Vue 3 as the New Default](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-as-the-new-default.html), Volar is [recommended](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#ide-support) in official Vue 3 docs